# URLConnection returning empty inputStream

Tags: java, url, inputstream, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to fetch input stream pdf from `URL Connection` but I am getting an empty input stream. Can anyone please tell me what is I am doing wrong? Following is the code:

```
<!-- language: java -->

URL fileUrl = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao3up7xudju4qm0/Amalgabond%20Adhesive%20Agent.pdf");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)fileUrl.openConnection();
connection.connect(); 
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
Log.i("TAG", "is.available(): " + is.available());
```

`is.available()` is returning `0` empty stream.

Comment: Its working great here, is.availbale() returns 15595 bytes.

Comment: I am stuck at this. I dont know Why I am getting `0` or sometimes `1`

Comment: Have you tried the URL with your browser before ?

Comment: Yes browser is showing the pdf file with this url `https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao3up7xudju4qm0/Amalgabond%20Adhesive%20Agent.pdf`

Comment: On which OS are you working ?

Comment: The only difference with your snippet, is that I changed the last line for : `System.out.println("is.available(): " + is.available());`

Comment: I am using Windows 8 ... Is there any `url encoding required`? becuase file name has `spaces` are these any issues?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50988/discussion-between-slaadvak-and-mustang)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695372/what-does-inputstream-available-do-in-java/3695378

Answer (score 3):

According to the javadoc, `available()` does not block and wait until all data is available, so you might have not completely received your stuff when its called.

You should use something like this instead of available() :

```
int bytesRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];

while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) > 0){

    // Do something here with buffer
}
```

`read()` is a blocking method.

Comment: How to print the contents using this buffer?

Comment: If you want to print text, you can do it with a scanner instead :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/3183264

Comment: Why you were getting bytes when you did `is.available()`?

Comment: Maybe, because my Internet connection has less latency than yours, so more bytes where read from the stream when I was calling `available()`.

Comment: @slaadvak It's a PDF. You can't use a Scanner on that.

Comment: You're right. But in this case, the page retrieved is in fact a Web page showing the pdf file. It's HTML, not a binary PDF.

Comment: You can't realistically use a Scanner on an HTML page either. You need an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the available() method. It doesn't tell you the length of the input stream, so the fact that it returns zero doesn't indicate that it's empty. See the Javadoc, where all this is explicitly stated.

Just read it until end of stream.

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to download a file from Dropbox, you should use the [Dropbox Java API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/java),  or maybe this [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621178/3183264). Otherwise, a URLConnection to a file on Dropbox will download a web page (in HTML) showing you a link to click (with a lot of other stuff !) for downloading your file.

Comment: I do not want to download the file. I just want to open it, retrieve `inputstream` and fetch bytes from it.